# Negative padding-top, fixed height, overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, height, overflow

how can I show only 200px (height) of my div, and skip the first 30px (top) ?

```
<div style="height:200px; overflow:hidden; padding-top:-30px">
A<br>B<br>C<br>D<br>E<br>F<br>G<br>
H<br>I<br>J<br>K<br>L<br>M<br>N<br>
O<br>P<br>Q<br>R<br>S<br>T<br>U<br>
V<br>W<br>X<br>Y<br>Z
</div>
```

Comment: You're going to need to rephrase or expand on your question. I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to use margin-top instead of padding-top. Padding can not be negative.